# Fetching data from user profile service throws NullReferenceException

Tags: user-profile-service, user

I am fetching the user data from the user profile service. I have created a custom property  for EmpId. When I try to access its value NullReferenceException is thrown.

How can I access the value from the custom property?

Please guide.

Comment: Can you check your custom property Default Privacy Setting.Set it to everyone and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of usage

```
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(ctx.Site);

            // Then load the UserProfileManager
            UserProfileManager mngr = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

            // Get the user’s profile
            UserProfile currentProfile = mngr.GetUserProfile(true);

            // If the user has a profile, get the SocialTagManager 
            if (currentProfile != null)
            {
                //Do your stuff
            }
```

Also have a look here (NOT best practice but it'll get you started) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms544366.aspx and here for custom properties 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms519896.aspx

Do remember to run a FULL Syncro or otherwise you custom property might not be having values in it already!

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Definitely perform the null check on the returned property value. That gets me every time.